# Tableau Stacked Bar Chart 100% gap to target

Tags: tableau-api, target, stacked-chart

I have a data set that looks like this:

[image]

I want to create a stacked bar chart in Tableau from this data that shows the Pipeline and the Approved and then the gap to the Target as a %. So for example: Ireland Tables Pipeline 33%, Ireland Tables Approved 33% and Ireland Tables Gap To Target 33%.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Stefan.

Comment: Hi Stefan, depending on how you want this to look, you could make a bullet chart for each pipeline with the goal set to your target figure and the bar showing progress? Your data layout is good, so you have a lot of options. Are you looking for vertical or horizontal charts?

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm looking for vertical stacked bar charts. But I'm open to suggestions if you feel a better option is available.

Comment: @BenP I suppose the question is if the target is exceeded, the gap to target is no longer a positive %. So maybe then you are right with a bullet chart?

Comment: Are you able to share your data file (or a sample) and i'll happily put something together?

Comment: Hi Ben, here is the link to the test data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ywdbcujujodmgrt/TablesChairs.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: My approach would be something like this: https://public.tableau.com/views/Actualtotargetsample/Sheet1?:embed=y&:display_count=yes&publish=yes
Tried this also with stacked bar charts but I can't work out a way to make the targets clear.

Comment: Hi Ben, this is close but you don't have the Pipeline data included in the horizontal bar.

Comment: Having a really hard time working both measures against the target - there are lots of ways to do one, but it seems two is tricky!

Comment: It sure is. I'm struggling too.

Comment: How about this: https://public.tableau.com/views/Actualtotargetsample/Sheet2?:embed=y&:display_count=yes&publish=yes workaround was to make the 'total' stack white, as excluding it will hide the target line too.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure this is the way I would like to achieve this. I will keep trying different things and come back if/when I find a solution.